# Android: Transfer pictures between applications

Tags: android

I have two application need to transfer data together using intent. I get problem with transfering large data - pictures, as it is limitted in android.

My first app stores picture as binary data in database (no local path existing). Now I want to transfer this picture to the second app (which impossible using intent as big).

Does someone give me an advice to solve this problem?

I have an idea that my second app will read directly from DB. 
Is it possible? Any example is appireciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably store images in the local file storage and their corresponding paths in the db. That way, you can easily send the Intent too.

Comment: I don't think your second app can access the Db of the first. Can't you have the first app save the image in the external storage and share the path? If everything is local, that should be the best.

Comment: The picture is get from camera shooting, then it is saved local, but it can be deleted by user or others app - which seems frequently in my case. That's why I have to save its binary data to database, and cannot using local path :( .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case you have to use ContentProvider, which allow you share data provider for your first app to the second.

This is a good link for you: http://mrbool.com/android-content-provider-how-to-use-content-provider-for-data-access/30446

As explain in the Google documentation, it's the mechanism in use to get Picture from the PictureGallery of Android, so I presume this approach is the best available on Android platform.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, you saved me too much time.